# Изменение стилей в динамически созданном iframe

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, iframe

Есть динамически созданный iframe через js

```
var frame=document.createElement("iframe");
frame.setAttribute("src",url);
frame.setAttribute("name",frameName);
frame.setAttribute("id",frameName);
frame.setAttribute("width","100%");
frame.setAttribute("height","100%");
frame.setAttribute("frameBorder",0);
frame.isLoaded=false;
document.body.appendChild(frame)
```

Можно ли изменить стили внутри фрейма с помощью js или css?

Comment: извне - никак :)

Comment: @Sublihim, обманывать не хорошо :) Можно, но при условиях безопасности

Answer (score 2):

В iframe можно применить стиль, если только **в iframe открывается страница с тем же домен на котором находится сам iframe**. Иначе это противоречит правилам безопасности [Same-origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy).

Изменить любой стиль в iframe можно одной строкой:

```
frame.contentWindow.document.ELEM.style.STYLE
```

Живой пример: 
https://jsfiddle.net/yuri_spivak/gcujtjmp/

Comment: Спасибо за помощь